# SQL foreign key constraint not failing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created tables for roles, users and their relation users_roles.But I am getting no error since users table is completely empty. and I can see entry in user_roles table. why this is so?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS role
 (  
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    roleName VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)

);

LOCK TABLES `role` WRITE;
ALTER TABLE `role` DISABLE KEYS ;
INSERT INTO `role` VALUES (1,'admin'),(2,'user');
ALTER TABLE `role` ENABLE KEYS ;
UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users_roles`;
CREATE TABLE `users_roles` (
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL REFERENCES user(username),
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES role(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


insert into users_roles values (1,1);
```

Comment: Here is a SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fad677/3.  I find this curious.

Comment: Where is user_id in table user, and after that table users_roles have PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`role_id`)??

Comment: Run `show create table users_roles`. You will see, there is no FK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always created foreign keys with a slightly different syntax, I've never seen it the way you have it.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users_roles`;
CREATE TABLE `users_roles` (
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`role_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY(role_id) REFERENCES role(id),
 FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES user(username)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As you can see here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16224c, this way of creating the foreign key works.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

You're missing the FOREIGN KEY in users_roles.The REFERENCES part should be on the foreign key as Dave has shown above, not on the column.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key definitions in *column_definition* part are ignored.

> **Important**
>
> [..]
>
> MySQL parses but ignores “inline REFERENCES specifications” (as
>   defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part
>   of the column specification. MySQL accepts REFERENCES clauses only
>   when specified as part of a separate FOREIGN KEY specification.

Found here: [*reference_definition*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-reference-definition)